# Laravel: add constraint on many-to-many relationships

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Consider this simple many-to-many relationship in Laravel:

```
class User extends Eloquent {
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Role');
    }
}
```

and

```
class Role extends Eloquent {
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User');
    }
}
```

This is ok with schema of `role_user` that keeps `user_id` and `role_id`.
But what we if have some other constraints? For example in an app like Github, user is admin in repository A and is regular user in repository B. So we add `repository_id` to `role_user` table, but when I want to query `user->roles` I want to look for that in current repository, *that I keep reference of `current_repository_id` in session*. What changes should I do in **models** to do that?

---

Note: I don't want to change anything in using-code! Isn't anyway to put filter logic in model declaration? Because I'm at the middle of big project and it's tough to change every usage. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
//User model 
public function roles()
{
    $repoID = MyApp::currentRepoID();

    return $this->belongsToMany('Role', 'pivot_table_name', 'user_id', 'role_id')
        ->wherePivot('repository_id', $repoID);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to add additional fields to the pivot table, you should use ->withPivot() method.
If your pivot table structure is like:

> id | role_id | user_id | repository_id

you should use

```
return $this->belongsToMany('Role', 'pivot_table_name', 'user_id', 'role_id')->withPivot('repository_id');
```

Then, wherever you use it, you have to do:

```
$role = Role::find(1);
$role->pivot->repository_id;
```

or

```
$user = User::find(1);
foreach ($user->roles as $role) {
    echo $role->pivot->repository_id;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to change anything in using-code! isn't anyway to put filter logic in model declaration? because I'm at the middle of big project and it's tough to change every usage.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Eloquent Triple Pivot](https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/Eloquent-triple-pivot) (also on Packagist), it sounds like it does exactly what you want.

You'd set up your Models as `User`, `Repository` and `Role` (a `User` has many `Repository`s and can have a `Role` in each). Then look at the docs on the Github page (particularly step 6), and you'd define this on your `Repository` model:

```
class Repository extends Eloquent {
    ...
    public function getRolesAttribute() {
        return $this->getThirdAttribute();
    }
}
```

Then you can simply call

```
$user = User::find(1);

$repo = $user->repositories->first();
// or
$repo = $user->repositories->find(73);

$roles = $repo->roles;

// Or the above can be condensed into just...
$roles = User::findOrFail( 1 )
             ->repositories()
             ->findOrFail( 73 )
             ->roles;
```